# Observed sun/moon rise/set times to nearest second?

Tags: the-moon, the-sun

Where can I find a list of observed (not computed) sun/moon rise/set 
times to the nearest second, along with the location (latitude, 
longitude, altitude [or enough information to find these three 
values]) and, ideally, weather conditions (temperature/pressure)?

Since it's hard to tell where the "middle" of the sun/moon is when 
it's setting, these would be the setting times for the lower or upper 
limb of the sun/moon.

Reason: I'm trying to compute sun/moon rise/set to the nearest second 
using high-precision data, and I'm curious to see if I can get 
anywhere near the actual observed time. My technique:

- Use NASA's Chebyshev approximations to find the positions of the 
  Sun and center of the Earth.
- Use an elliptical (not spherical) model of the Earth to find the 
  ICRF xyz coordinates of a given location at a given time. This 
  includes compensating for altitude and precession.
- Model refraction based on weather conditions, including adjusting pressure for altitude (weather stations report air pressure normalized to sea level, which isn't the same as actual air pressure, especially at higher altitudes).

I realize down-to-the-second computations of sun/moon rise/set are 
probably impossible, in part because refraction depends on more than 
just local conditions, but I'm curious to try.

Comment: That would depend on what is on the horizon of your observation site. If you are in the mountains, the observed sunset time will be earlier than if you are in a desert plain.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such database set. However, you might be interested in reading (if you haven’t already) this article: https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-news/we-dont-really-know-when-the-sun-rises/